# Do we use Redux for all state updates?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Background:

I have started to build an application using React. The whole UI is based on a big object Survey with several(15-20) components updating parts of that object. The survey object is fetched with a single server call and the object is saved with another call the server. All the element updates made in each component is meant to update part of the big Survey object.

I am planning to use Redux to do the state updates for each elements/fields as it clean and central state management.

It seems in order to do that I need to bind 'onChange' event handlers to all elements. Every time a text box value change, for example, an action is fired and a corresponding reducer intercepts and update the state.

So for the following element in a component,

```
<input
  className="form-control form-control-lg"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Username"
  value={this.props.username}
  onChange={this.changeUsername} />
```

The following action is fired

```
onChangeUsername(){
  dispatch({ type: UPDATE_FIELD_AUTH, key: 'username', value }),
  ...
}
```

And the reducer updates the state...

```
(survey = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {    
    case UPDATE_FIELD_AUTH:
      return { ...survey , [action.key]: action.value };
    default:
      return state;
}
```

Look, in short, we are doing the following to update state for a single field:
element event handler -> dispatch Redux action -> Redux reducer updates the field

```
    Survey
        -> Name
        -> Description
        -> Section
            ->Name
            ->Number
            ->Question
                ->Name
                ->Type
                ->Option
                    ->Name
                    ->Type
                    ->Value
```

Question
There are probably 100 such fields in the application and the same field might be update from two different components. Is this the model to follow?

Comment: It all depends on how your app is shaped, I would not recommend dispatching an action for `input` `onChange` events, that'll trigger an event for every single time you type something (if you use redux devtools you'll see what I'm talking about). That's something I would rather keep in the state of the component. Then on submit or on "next' you can dispatch an action that saves such value into your app state, so you can access it later or submit it. I mean there's much more to it that I can't fit in a comment so maybe I'll write up an answer as soon as I have time.

Comment: @G4bri3l  If you wait for the 'submit' or a button it might be too late for some other component to use the value. The other component might be using a stale value of the state.

Comment: I see, so basically you would need other components to be up to date with the state of the survey at all times ?

Comment: @G4bri3l Yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition is that you want to use single dispatcher for multiple `onChange` events

There's the component:

```js
const inputView = props => (
  <input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Username"
  value={this.props.username}
  onChange={e => { this.props.onChange('username', e.target.value) }} 
  />
);
```

There's the dispatcher:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onChange: (key, value) => dispatch({ 
    type: actionTypes.UPDATE_FIELD, 
    key, 
    value
  }),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(inputView);
```

There's the reducer:

```js
const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_FIELD:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.key]: action.value,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Is this efficient?**
Absolutely yes.
Since multiple inputs go though the same condition, the switch statement isn't that complex.
Moreover, if you have more components/sections, **multiple reducers** is always an option.

According to [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), even `setState` doesn't update immediately, but new props will always immediately fire render function. So this central store implementation is actually better than keeping states inside each components, and you shouldn't have to worry about chained states may out of async or cause side effects.

---

**Update**
*There is the update for nested state, which didn't show up in the original question, and `input` setup in the question doesn't match the data structure.*

Given a state like this. Assuming user cannot remove question, and each section will be rendered in order.
It's easy to track the **index**, since we don't want to search the state in every `onChange` event.

```js
const state = {
  Survey: {
    Name: '',
    Description: '',
    Section: [
      {
        Name: '',
        Number: 0,
        Question: [
          {
            Name: '',
            Type: '',
            Value: '1', // input value should be in this level
            Option: [ // handle input type="select"
              { value: '1', displayValue: '1' },
              { value: '2', displayValue: '2' },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The idea is to create a deep copy in the lowest level.

```js
const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_FIELD:
      const survey = { ...state.Survey };
      const section = { ...survey.Section[action.sectionIdx] };
      const question = { ...section.Qustion[action.questionIdx] };
      question.Value = action.value;
      section[sectionIdx].Qustion = question;
      survey.Section = section;
      return {
        ...survey,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

**Additional information:**
The official link for [Correct Approach: Copying All Levels of Nested Data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach:-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data)

Comment: I have just included a cut down version of the 'Survey' object in my question. The thing is you need to update 'Option' property deep down the object hierarchy.

Comment: @fahmi the question is about big object, but you actually mean deep object. The solution is to only create deep copy in the lowest value. I know the `option` is used to render select input, but I can't see where you want to save the value, so I added myself.